Does retirement (pre-Full Retirement Age) qualify for a special enrollment period for the affordable care act?
If I retire before I am old enough to be eligible for Medicare, and it wasn't a forced retirement by my employer. Do I qualify for a special enrollment period for the Affordable Care Act (aka ObamaCare)?
Also, if I decide to take COBRA health insurance for a few months and later drop it, how does that change the eligibility?


If I retire before I am old enough to be eligible for Medicare, and it
wasn't a forced retirement by my employer. Do I qualify for a special
enrollment period for the Affordable Care Act (aka ObamaCare)?

Yes. You get a 60-day special enrollment period when you lose your employer-based health insurance, including when you quit your job.

Also, if I decide to take COBRA health insurance for a few months and
later drop it, how does that change the eligibility?

You do not qualify for a special enrollment period for dropping COBRA. So if you go with COBRA, you should wait until an open enrollment period to switch to a marketplace plan.
